# How to dynamically import a video + create an absolute path to it all inside an axios call response?

Tags: vue.js, vite, assets

I have this template bit:

```
<video controls autoplay muted loop>
  <source :src="videoFileName" />
</video>
```

The video source is fetched thus:

```
axios.get(`/project/v1/post/${route.params.id}`)
  .then((response) => {
    videoFileName.value = `@/assets/vids/${response.data.meta.video}`
  })
  .catch((error) => {})
```

This fails because Vue/Vite does not replace "@/" with the corresponding absolute path so the template section receives "@/..." which it can't make sense of.

How can I get the absolute path in my call response?

https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#dynamic-import seems to be the way to go, however I'm not sure how to integrate it into my non-sync axios call.

Comment: Have tried  ```.then(async (response) => {
    videoFileName.value = await  import(`@/assets/vids/${response.data.meta.video}`)
  })```?

Comment: Getting this error: "error TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier '@/assets/vids/my-video.mp4'"